# Al mostrar los registros insertarlos al mismo tiempo

Tags: mysql

Tengo una 3 tablas en mi base de datos

```
fecha_busqueda         fecha_encontrar               fecha_resultado
-------------         ---------------                ----------------
id_fechab int         id_fechae  int                  id_fechar    int
fechab    datetime    fechae     datatime             fechar       datetime
```

Este es el asunto

La tabla fecha_busqueda tiene registros de fechas completa
y la tabla fecha_encontrar tiene registros de fechas que no estan en la de fecha_busqueda.

Realize un inner join para comparar que fechas no estan en la de fecha_encontrar
entonces me lanzo una lista de fechas.

Lo que quiero hacer es que esa lista de fechas que no encontro insertarlos en la de fecha_resultado junto con la de fecha_encontrar, me doy a entender?

ese resultado que me arrojo hacer un insert de todo la fecha_encontrar y insertar los resultados que no encontro en la de fecha_busqueda

y asi obtengo una fecha_resultado con el registro de fecha_encontrar y la que no encontro.

Ej.

fecha_busqueda tengo 10 registros y la de fecha_encontrar tengo 7
quiere decir que no hay 3 fechas en encontrar a comparado del la otra tabla
entonces me lanza las fechas que no encontro

y quiero mostrar todas las 7 fechas de fecha_encontrar y insertarlas en fecha_resultado junto con las que no encontro y asi tengo 10 fechas iguales ala otra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que he entendido a lo que te refieres...

**EDICIÓN:** No te había entendido, he modificado la respuesta

No necesitas un INNER JOIN, con insertar todos los resultados de ambas tablas sería suficiente.

Para eso necesitarías hacer un `INSERT` con un `SELECT` dentro:

```
INSERT INTO fecha_resultado
        (id_fechar, fechar)
SELECT id_fechab, fechab
FROM   fecha_busqueda
WHERE  id_fechab IS NOT NULL
 UNION
SELECT id_fechae, fechae
FROM   fecha_encontrar
WHERE  id_fechab IS NOT NULL
```